# Why execution context of function B doesnt pass its activation-object into function A-s scope-chain-object, that A has acces to variables of B

Tags: javascript, executioncontext, scope-chain

Hy guys thanks for reading my question. So I am researching this problem since 2 days and didnt find any answer, so thanks for helping. So here is the below code:

```js
function A(){
    console.log(myVar);
}
function B(){
    var myVar = 2;
    A();
}
B();
```

So here if I run this code, from function A will get an error massage: "myVar is not defined", because it doesnt have access to the variables of function B and this is what I dont udnerstand.

So as far as I know when the code starts to run, the global execution context will be created by the javascript engine and each time the engine hits a parentheses for function call - and some other conditions are met- , javascript creates an execution context object for the function which has been called.

It should include and the scope chain, the activation object and the "this" keyword and In the scope chain should be all the variable/activation objects of the parent execution contexts

So with otherwords function A in its scope-chain-object should have function B-s all variables (but obviously it is not the case and this is what I dont understand).

But if I run this code, where function A-s definition is nested in function B:

```js
function B(){
  var myVar = 2;
 A();
   
    function A(){
    console.log(myVar);
    }
}
B();
```

So now function A will have access to the variables declaired and initialized in function B.

But in my head it shouldnt matter, where function A have been defined since it has been called in the context of function B.

Even when the this keywords value is defined in the creation phase, its value will based on, where and how the function is called, not where it has been defined.

Thanks guys that your read threw my tons of words, I really appriciate it.
And thanks for every answer or any kind of article or matterial, that could help me understand this anomaly.

Cheers and thanks a lot.

Comment: Scope in JavaScript (and similar languages) is **lexical**.  That means that what's in scope depends on how the program *looks*, and not what happens when it runs.

Comment: You should study the ECMAScript spec concerning Environment Records. You can think of these as buckets of stuff. They contain records for functions and variables and other code block types of structures. There are many Environment Records in every JavaScript application. In your first example, `function A` is recorded in one and `function B` is in another. The idea of what the keyword `this` represents is defined by the Environment Record - hence `A` and `B` have different a different `this'.  Read more here: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-environment-records

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend your answer, it has helped me a lot.
Cheers

Comment: "*activation object*"? What articles are you reading? That term is from ES3.

Comment: Yes you are right, but in many articles (google results) even from 2017 this name  "activation object" is used, to describe the changes to the variable object, when the function is called. And the fact it is ES3 expression is not highlighted. But since then I have found out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript a Lexical Environment of a function is called *lexical* because it is determined by the static structure of a program, not where the function is called from. It means that the outer Lexical Environment of the `function A()` will be the environment within which the `function A()` is declared, not called.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend it your answer was really helpful